# How to Contour Human Body in an image using PpenCv?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am currently trying to contour a human body from an image, but I am stuck right now.

I have taken different video lectures on contour, but they were related to objects like rectangles, circles and other simle shapes.

Can someone guide me in Human body contour? [This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMbfl.png) shows an example of contour I am looking for.

Comment: You can't expect us to write an entire tutorial as an answer to your question. Voting to close this as too broad.

Comment: I was just asking to guide me through this problem . Any link any blog would be useful

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand that detecting a human body is not so simple because it is hard to diferentiate the background from the body. That being said, if you have a simple background like the uploaded image, you can try to apply number of image tranformations (like applying binary threshold, otsu... look at opencv documentation - [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html)) to make your ROI "stand out" so you can detect with `cv2.findContours()` - same as drawing contour for circles, squares, etc. You can even apply `cv2.Canny()` (Canny edge detection) which detects a wide range of edges in the image and then search for contour. Here is an example for your image (the results could be better if the image didn't already have a red contour surrounding the body). Steps are desribed in comments in the code. Note that this is very basic stuff and would not work in most cases as the human detection is very difficult and broad question.

Example:

```
import cv2

# Read image and convert it to grayscale. 
img = cv2.imread('human.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Search for edges in the image with cv2.Canny().
edges = cv2.Canny(img,150,200)

# Search for contours in the edged image with cv2.findContour().
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Filter out contours that are not in your interest by applying size criterion.
for cnt in contours:
    size = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if size > 100:
        cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], -1, (255,0,0), 3)

# Display the image.
cv2.imshow('img', img)
```

Result:

[image]

Here is another useful link in the OpenCV documentation regarding this subject: [Background Subtraction](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html). Hope it helps a bit and gives you an idea on how to proceede. Cheers!

Comment: background subtraction will help in the case of videos where the background is stationary and the object is moving.

Comment: Yes thank you...I forgot to add that.